# Exercise: second-order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system

$$\begin{cases} y'_{1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\;y_{1} - \dfrac{3}{2}\;y_{2} \\ y'_{2} = - \dfrac{3}{2}\;y_{1} + \dfrac{1}{2}\;y_{2}\end{cases}$$

Retrieving $y_{2}$ from the first one

$$y_{2} = - \dfrac{2}{3}\;y'_{1} + \dfrac{1}{3}\;y_{1}$$

Now, the result I should get by replacing $y_{2}$ in the second one is

$$y''_{1}  - y'_{1} + 2y_{1} = 0$$

Yes I know how to resolv a second-order differential equation. What I would like to know, is how to get this equation by replacing in the second one

Comment: Make the ansatz $$y_1=e^{\lambda t}$$

Comment: Yes I know how to resolv a second-order differential equation. What I would like to know, is how to get this equation

Comment: Just plug it in?

Comment: Take the derivative of your expression for $y_2$ and plug it in the second equation.

Comment: @WarreG this is the solution! Thanks!